# Travelling to the US on tourist visa (Covid 19)

Tags: visas, usa, covid-19, tourist-visas

I am an Indian passport holder having a German Permanent Residency. I have a 10 year US B1/B2 visa. I am going to the US (transiting in Mexico for 30 days). Do the entry restrictions apply to tourist visas? if yes, does anything change if I am not flying from India or the Schengen region?

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any (and have not been any) entry restrictions to the US for people on tourist visas entering the US by air, as long as you have not been to Mainland China, Iran the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, Brazil, South Africa, or India in the previous 14 days. You need to get a negative COVID-19 test within 72 hours of boarding your flight to the US.